# Android Java Calendar getDisplayName/s returning null

Tags: java, android, string, calendar, null

```
timeOfMark = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
Map<String, Integer> what = timeOfMark.getDisplayNames(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : what.entrySet())
    {
        Log.e(pair.getKey(), Integer.toString(pair.getValue()));
    }
```

This case crashes my android app, because Log.e cannot accept null string.

It is same thing with

```
timeOfMark.getDisplayName(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I tried many variations with input parameters. For locale I also did Locale.getDefault() and many other. Still same ****

No darn luck. Is there anything to solve this? Or a easy workaround?

Comment: What are you trying to get ?  Check my answer to know more about getDisplayNames

Comment: I want time, days, date. Not sure yet. But I am sure that, whatever I put into field, I should get string. 

Ok, will do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> public Map getDisplayNames(int field,int style,Locale locale)

This method returns a Map containing all display names in style and locale and their field values, or `null` if no string representation is available.

```
timeOfMark.getDisplayName(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

There is not String representation of HOUR, i.e you can express `HOURS` in `string` like we did for MONTH And DAY_OF_WEEK

Try WEEK, MONTH 
Example

```
 Map< String, Integer> representations = 
      now.getDisplayNames(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.ALL_STYLES, locale);
```

You will get

```
 {Apr=3, April=3, Aug=7, August=7, Dec=11, December=11, Feb=1, February=1, Jan=0, January=0, Jul=6, July=6, Jun=5, June=5, Mar=2, March=2, May=4, Nov=10, November=10, Oct=9, October=9, Sep=8, September=8}
```

For Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK

```
{Fri=6, Friday=6, Mon=2, Monday=2, Sat=7, Saturday=7, Sun=1, Sunday=1, Thu=5, Thursday=5, Tue=3, Tuesday=3, Wed=4, Wednesday=4}
```

Try here

http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/18596

Comment: Oh, I see, it makes sense for both methods (getDisplayname/s). Why the heck I thought that integer types are automatically converted and returned as string? Wow kinda lame, but now I see problem.

Damn shame I can't vote up you :)

Comment: for future references:

Integer.toString(timeOfMark.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

returns 24h representation of time in string.